# Is it true that any étale morphism is quasi-affine?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, etale-covers

Let $\phi:X\to Y$ be an étale morphism  of Noetherian schemes. Does $\phi$ have to be quasi-affine? In other words, if $Y$ is affine does it mean that $X$ is quasi-affine?

It will follow from the fact that quasi-finite morphisms are quasi-affine, but I do not know whether this is true.

Comment: $\phi$ will be quasi-affine iff it is separated, which is not automatic for etale morphisms. The nontrivial implication is [Zariski's Main Theorem](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02LR).

Comment: Silly example: the line with two origins projecting to $\mathbb{A}^1$ is étale (it's even a local isomorphism!) but it is certainly not quasi-affine

Comment: As Marc Hoyois indicates:  a quasi-finite morphism is quasi-affine if and only if it separated. To prove this, you can use ZMT (as he says). Indeed, note that a quasi-finite separated morphism factors as an open immersion and a finite morphism. Since finite morphisms are affine, it follows that every quasi-finite separated morphism is quasi-affine.